# Powershell command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Good evening,

I would like to execute the following powershell command in a batch:

```
$data = Import-Csv C:\Users\powershell\input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..41);1..25 | %{$data[0].($_+16) = $data[$_].16};($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ";" -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file  C:\Users\powershell\output.txt
```

For this I use the following batch:

```
@echo off

powershell -Executionpolicy ByPass -Command "$data = Import-Csv C:\Users\powershell\input.txt -delimiter ';' -Header (1..41);1..25 | %{$data[0].($_+16) = $data[$_].16};($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ';' -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file  C:\Users\powershell\output.txt"
```

Unfortunately, it does not work properly, the command is executed, the file is opened but not saved, the file is only to be saved and not opened.

Can someone tell me why? How does it work properly?

example-input:

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;
```

example-output:

```
Klaus;Möller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;1;2;3;4;5;6;;;;;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;DE1;
```

Comment: Can you show us the csv file?

Comment: I edit the post for seconds...

Comment: The issue with the command is `out-file` so try to use `powershell -Executionpolicy ByPass -Command "$data = Import-Csv C:\Users\powershell\input.txt -delimiter ';' -Header (1..41);1..25 | %{$data[0].($_+16) = $data[$_].16};($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ';' -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' " > C:\Users\powershell\output.txt` instead

Comment: The command I provided seems to work for me when I have the csv file you put in the question. It had the intended output as well.

Comment: I just tested it, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. It looks like he can't find the path C:\Users\powershell\input.txt but the file is there.

Comment: The main issue with your command is that you need to escape the nested doublequote, in your `-replace` string. On top of that, you're using the alias `%` which also needs to be escaped. In addition to that, get rid of `-Executionpolicy ByPass`, the execution policy is only for running scripts, not commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

powershell -Executionpolicy ByPass -Command^
 $data = Import-Csv C:\Users\powershell\input.txt -encoding OEM -delimiter ';' -Header (1..41);1..25 ^|^
 %%{$data[0].($_+16) = $data[$_].16};($data[0] ^|^
 convertto-csv -delimiter ';' -NoType ^|^
 select -skip 1^) -replace '\^"' ^|^
 out-file C:\Users\powershell\output.txt -encoding OEM
```

Double quotes within double quotes passed to `powershell.exe` may need escaping with `\`, else the inner double quotes may be stripped during parsing. batch-file may need double quotes escaped with `^`. Due to issues, decided to remove outer double quotes and escape as needed.

- `^` esacape at end of line is a line continuation in batch-file.
- `^` escape before a character makes the character literal in batch-file. For characters any of `)|`.
- `%` escape before `%` makes the character literal in batch-file. Does not include `for` variables which can use `%%`.
- `OEM` encoding used for input and output to match `example-input` as posted in the question.